# instagram media search timestamp issues

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api

I am using instagram's media search api

https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=8.51&lng=115.239394&MAX_TIMESTAMP=xyz&MIN_TIMESTAMP=abc&client_id=my_client_id

Now I am making calls to this api under a for-loop and changing the value of min and max timestamps in each iteration. So that I get images for that timeframe.

The issue I am facing is I get same result (or set of images) in each iteration. So changing timestamps has no effect on the result.

Is it because of caching? or Instagram does not allow requests in iteration like this? Or there is some other way e.g. pagination or something to make such requests?

Here is the code (in python):

```
import urllib2
import datetime
import time
import json

clientId = 'ef63de4634b344e3856b4f4138a8db56'
city = "Bali"
baliLat = '8.51'
baliLong = '115.239394'
distance = 1000

def callApi(startStamp, endStamp):
    searchStr = 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/search?lat=' + baliLat + '&lng=' + baliLong + '&client_id=' + clientId + '&MAX_TIMESTAMP=' + str(endStamp) + '&MIN_TIMESTAMP=' + str(startStamp) + '&distance='  + str(distance) + '&count=10'
    print searchStr
    response = urllib2.urlopen(searchStr)
    res = json.loads(response.read())
    return res

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # call instagram api for 1 year for each month for 1st week.
    # compare the dates of creation for each month.
    start = '1/05/2014'
    startDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(start, '%d/%m/%Y')
    count = 0
    result = {}
    while count < 12:
        endDate = startDate + datetime.timedelta(days=7)
        minStamp = time.mktime(startDate.timetuple())
        maxStamp = time.mktime(endDate.timetuple())
        res = callApi(minStamp, maxStamp)
        result[str(startDate)] = res
        startDate = startDate + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
        count += 1
    f = open('out-y.json', 'w')
    f.write(json.dumps(result))
    f.close()
```

Comment: how many days you're trying to get?

Comment: 7 days (for each month). There was no intersection. Is there anything else I should be aware of?

Comment: post the code, it should not give u same result if if u are making too many calls, something in your code may be

Comment: I added the code I am using.

Answer (score 2):

`MAX_TIMESTAMP` and `MIN_TIMESTAMP` should be lower case: `max_timestamp` and `min_timestamp`

the api documentation on Instagram shows params in upper case, its misleading, it should be all lower case.

Comment: I tried using lower case max_timestamp and min_timestamp but they dont work. So I resorted to using uppercase which atleast works, not correctly though.

Comment: if u use uppercase then it is ignored and u are getting latest photos, if u are using lowercase and you get nothing then it is correct, there is no photos in the time range or your time values are incorrect, check for photos with your times here: http://www.gramfeed.com/instagram/map

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the same issue over the last week and I think my problems stemmed from time.mktime() - this assumes that dates are set to the local timezone, rather than the UTC/GMT times that the Instagram data is based on. Try replacing all your time.mktime() calls with calendar.timegm() and see if that does the trick - seemed to fix the issue for me.

Comment: No the change did not fix the issue for me. My code is there, can you replace time.mktime by calendar.timegm and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Instagram's API uses timestamps in seconds, not milliseconds. Divide all your timestamps by `1000`.

Comment: Tried this. Does not work. Still get the same results for both the calls which are for consecutive months.